# How can one receive a German phone number before going to Germany?

Tags: germany, communication

It would be really helpful to call Germany. I did call on my non-German number but used like €5 in a few minutes, but it was worth the call.

But for other things, it would be useful to call without paying an arm and a leg, so having a German number before arriving would help a lot.

How can I get a German phone number to call like nomally, before I arrive in Germany? This includes a digital phone number that can call over VOIP like Google Voice (GV does not have German phone numbers), but not that charge expensive per-minute rates which I can already do with my non-German phone number?

Comment: Is this a number not reachable by WhatsApp/Signal/Telegram? That could be an easy fix without needing a german number

Comment: There is a service called satellite (www.satellite.me) that gives you a german number and works via an app. However, they will send you a letter when you register and I don't know if it's available to people living outside Germany.

Comment: The places I want to call are universities, jobs, immigration, etc, all things that are not going to be using mobile apps and actually might be using wired telephones (landlines).

Comment: No adverting intended but we use https://deutschlandanrufen.com/ . Prices are 1c/min landline and 3c/min mobile.

Comment: @Hilmar that is precisely advertising FWIW. I think you meant that they do not pay you to advertise.

Comment: @user253751. Fair point. What I mean here is "the product works great for me but it may or may not work for you" and "I receive no benefits whatsoever for mentioning this product". Personally I think that specific product recommendations based on hands on experience are quite valuable but the forum isn't a marketplace or review side either.  I'm not sure what the right balance is and what recommendation are "ok" under what conditions.

Answer (score 4):

You don’t need a German phone number to call German mobile or landline numbers cheaply. You just need a provider which has decent rates for calling German numbers.

Nowadays, many landline or mobile providers include calls to landlines in a lot of countries and mobiles in a few. I know I can use my mobile phone and call landlines in dozens of countries for free for instance.

Some providers will ask for some kind of extra subscription to add this to your plan if it’s not included.

If this is not available on your existing network/plan or in your country (or it’s too expensive), nearly any VOIP service provider will do. Rates vary a lot, between prepaid/pay as you go and subscription services at various monthly rates, so you may have to shop around, but even Skype has calls to German landlines at 2.1p/minute and to German mobiles at 9.3p/minute for the most basic pay as you go plan, and it can be cheaper with subscriptions.

Google voice has rates between 1 cent/minute for landlines and 25 cents/minute for the most expensive mobiles, with most others at less than 4 cents/minute.

Remember that many tools/apps you can use to call other users of the same app for free allow you to purchase credits or subscriptions to also call regular phone numbers.

Some subscriptions can also get you a German phone number (which is useful if you need to give a number people can call you on). Again, large number of providers for this, so you’ll have to shop around, but remember you don’t actually need a German phone number, you just need a provider which allows you to call German numbers cheaply.

Also note that some countries have restrictions in place which will allow VoIP providers to give you a number from that country only with a proof of address in that country. Not sure if that applies for Germany though.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this, but the reviews look good and it seems quite economical. Check out https://www.ringover.com/

Seems you can just register, choose a plan and start using a german number.

Comment: I looked at their site: $19 for "Unlimited calls to 90 destinations" is pretty good, and way better than paying by minute!